# Form Validation Laravel dynamic field

Tags: jquery, laravel, validation

I want to make validation for the newly add field.
the name and description for the warehouse is already built, but I cannot set the validation for the Rak.

This is my HTML

```
@extends('layout.main')

@Section('container')
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
    <h1 class="h2">Create Warehouse</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-7">
    <form method="post" action="/warehouse" id="myForm" name="myForm">
        @csrf
        <div class="row mb-2">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm @error('name') is-invalid  @enderror" id="name"
                    name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
                @error('name')
                <div id="validationServernameFeedback" class="invalid-feedback">
                    {{ $message }}
                </div>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mb-2">
            <label for="desc" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Description</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm @error('desc') is-invalid  @enderror" id="desc"
                    name="desc" value="{{ old('desc') }}">
                @error('desc')
                <div id="validationServercust_add1Feedback" class="invalid-feedback">
                    {{ $message }}
                </div>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>
        <div
            class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
            <h1 class="h4">Rak</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <div class="input-group m-1">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm border-0" id="DeleteRow" type="button">
                            <i class="bi bi-trash" data-feather="x-circle"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="typehead form-control form-control-sm @error('rak') is-invalid  @enderror" placeholder="Rak Name" name="rak" id="rak_1">
                    @error('rak')
                <div id="validationServerrakFeedback" class="invalid-feedback">
                    {{ $message }}
                </div>
                @enderror
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <div class="input-group m-1">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Rak Description" name="rak_desc[]" id="rakdesc_1" >
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="newinput"></div>
        <div class="row mb-5 mt-3 ">
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <button id="rowAdder" type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm float-end border-0 ">
                    <span class="bi bi-plus-square-dotted"></span> Add rak
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
    </form>
</div>

@endsection
```

[image]

This is my controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'desc' => 'required|max:255',
        ]);
        foreach ($request->rak as $index  => $name) {
            $validatedData = $request->validate([
                'rak'.$index => 'required|max:255'
            ]);
            $validatedRak['rak_name'] = $name;
            $validatedRak['created_by'] = auth()->user()->id;
            $validatedRak['updated_by'] = auth()->user()->id;
            $validatedRak['branch'] = auth()->user()->branch;
            $validatedRak['warehouse_name'] = $request->name;
            dd($validatedRak);
            warehouserak::create($validatedRak);
        } 
        $validatedData['created_by'] = auth()->user()->id;
        $validatedData['updated_by'] = auth()->user()->id;
        $validatedData['branch'] = auth()->user()->branch;
        
 
        warehouse::create($validatedData);
   
        $request->session()->flash('Success','Warehouse Created Successfully!');
        return redirect('/warehouse');
    }
```

What I want to do is, **the rak field must be inputed by user**, but I cannot get error that I wanted.
Please help me with this case.

Regards,
Andri

Answer (score 0):

for array validation you can use this

```
 $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'desc' => 'required|max:255',
        'rak.*' => 'required|max:255', 
    ]);
```

Comment: Hi,I already try the same method.,. but still don't show the error message...

Comment: $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'desc' => 'required|max:255',
            'rak' => 'array',
            'rak.*' => 'required|max:255'
        ]);